# mail() sends emails twice when a RewriteRule is used

Tags: php

This one baffles me, and if its not script specific then its something wrong with the Amazon AMI hosting my application.

I'm posting the exact contents of my .htaccess and index file. The only difference is the email I'm sending to.

this is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and this is my index.php

```
<?php

mail('me@email.com', '', '7');
```

when i load my index page i will get 2 e-mails with my current set up. But if I comment out the RewriteRule and load the index page, I correctly get 1 email sent to me.

Has anyone encountered this?

Edit:
access_log shows this with RewriteRule

```
[21/Feb/2013:03:48:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
[21/Feb/2013:03:48:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
```

access_log shows this without RewriteRule

```
[21/Feb/2013:03:47:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
[21/Feb/2013:03:47:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 295 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"
```

Comment: what am i looking for?

Comment: Dude, accesslog of sendmail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're routing every single request for a non-existent file to `index.php`.  Browsers will automatically make a request to http://yourdomain.com/favicon.ico when a page is loaded.  Since this file doesn't exist yet on your site, `index.php` is getting hit again.  You can avoid this by checking `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` in `index.php` and only generating mail if it's supposed to be a page (in contrast to an image file, etc).

For example:

```
if (!preg_match('/\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|txt)$/i', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    mail('me@email.com', '', '7');
```

That checks for `ico`, `jpg`, `png`, `gif` and `txt` files.

Comment: yes, this was the idea that i was formulating. So since i'm routing all trafic to my index.php i can either create a favicon.ico or i can do logic to only sendmail if its been loaded by a page request? Is there a way to have an .htaccess rule to delegate this?

Comment: The only two "auto requests" you should have to worry about are favicon.ico and robots.txt.  But that's not a guarantee -- for example, any should-be 404 errors are going to end up hitting this script.

Comment: i see, okay thanks for the insight. i didnt know these type of issues could exists with rewrite rules.

Comment: well that was a no go, i'm still getting duplicate emails hmm

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the RewriteRule being incorrect

This was the one causing the duplicate emails

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

the fix was to add "/" to the rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

my assumption is that the original `RewriteRule` wasn't correctly capturing the `GET` requests. As **N Rohler** pointed out that the `favicon.ico` was being requested but the request came in as `"/favicon.ico"`

which was not being captured by the original `RewriteRule`